# OpenCV darken oversaturated webcam image

Tags: python, opencv, camera, webcam

I have a (fairly cheap) webcam which produces images which are far lighter than it should be. The camera does have brightness correction - the adjustments are obvious when moving from light to dark - but it is consistently far to bright.

I am looking for a way to reduce the brightness without iterating over the entire frame (OpenCV Python bindings on a Raspberry Pi). Does that exist? Or better, is there a standard way of sending hints to a webcam to reduce the brightness?

```
import cv2

# create video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
window = cv2.namedWindow("output", 1)

while True:

    # read the frames
    _,frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("output",frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(33)== 27:
        break

# Clean up everything before leaving
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: A few questions: 1) Can you update your question with a snippet showing where you get an image in your app? I'd like to see the exact source of the data you have. Also it's standard practice on SO to post your code. 2) Do you already have OpenCV (cv2) working on Raspberry Pi? That would imply that you already have numpy. If so, then it should be easy. 3) Do you want to just scale down the brightness or do something more sophisticated like adjust gamma?

Comment: The code is not yet running on the Pi - I am currently developing elsewhere to avoid networking. Small steps. Both the Pi and the desktop are running Arch, so the environment should be fairly similar. 

I didn't add code because it manifests itself on any image capture. It didn't seem like a "grab image -> show image" snippet would add anything to the question. 

Whatever is best - I'd probably like to try both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to adjust webcam parameters is the VideoCapture `set()` method (providing your camera supports the interface. Most do in my experience). This avoids the performance overhead of processing the image yourself.

[VideoCapture::set](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set)

`CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS` or `CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION` would appear to be what you want.

Comment: That's awesome. I've been looking around for a more detailed explanation of what that does (it appears to maintain the effect after the program closes, ie re-run the program without the option set and it will still darken the image). Am I just failing at Google?

Comment: Im not too sure how it works, but I think it just calls standard functions in the UVC (USB Video Class) protocol. Perhaps your camera has some non-volatile memory which stores the previous settings, or maybe it might change the settings at the usb device level (so unplugging/replugging the device would clear it)

Comment: I couldn't ever find in the documentation but it takes a float... **0.0 is darkest** and **100.0 is lightest** from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot Raspberry Pi is just running a regular OS. What an awesome machine. Thanks for the code which confirms that you just have a regular cv2 image.

Simple vectorized scaling (without playing with each pixel) should be simple. Below just scales every pixel. It would be easy to add a few lines to normalize the image if it has a major offset.

```
import numpy
#...
scale = 0.5  # whatever scale you want
frame_darker = (frame * scale).astype(numpy.uint8)
#...
```

Does that look like the start of what you want?

Comment: Yeah it's a wonderful little thing! That does appear to do the job - I'll accept the properties approach, however, as it seems the more "official" way of solving the problem and transfers to other languages better. Thanks!

Comment: @KendallV certainly if you can tell the camera to give you better images that's always a better choice. You can come back to this one and add a little analysis if you can't get predictable behavior from the camera.